# Atleast one Checkbox should be Selected in Single Row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I want to have at least one checkbox selected. I have multiple rows with multiple checkbox on each row and I want to have at least one checkbox selected in each row based on selection of select option on each row. if selected false, then no need to have the validation of at least one checkbox selected, but if selected true then the criteria of at least one checkbox selected should be satisfied.
**For Row1:**

```
<select  id="demo1" name="demo1" class="form-control" style="background-color: #e7e7ed">
    <option value="false">false</option>
    <option value="true">true</option>
</select>
<div class="row">
    <div class="edit-weekDays-selector col-7 edit-weekDays-margin" id="editWeekDaysColor">
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekDays1" id="weekday-mon1" value="MON"class="weekday" />
        <label for="weekday-mon">M</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekDays1" id="weekday-tue1" value="TUE"class="weekday" />
        <label for="weekday-tue">T</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekDays1" id="weekday-wed1" value="WED"class="weekday" />
        <label for="weekday-wed">W</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekDays1" id="weekday-thu1" value="THU" class="weekday" />
        <label for="weekday-thu">T</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekDays1" id="weekday-fri1" value="FRI" class="weekday" />
        <label for="weekday-fri">F</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekDays1" id="weekday-sat1" value="SAT" class="weekday" />
        <label for="weekday-sat">S</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekDays1" id="weekday-sun1" value="SUN" class="weekday" />
        <label for="weekday-sun">S</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**For Row2:**

```
<select  id="demo2" name="demo2" class="form-control" style="background-color: #e7e7ed">
    <option value="false">false</option>
    <option value="true">true</option>
</select>
<div class="row">
    <div class="edit-weekDays-selector col-7 edit-weekDays-margin" id="editWeekDaysColor">
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekDays2" id="weekday-mon2" value="MON"class="weekday" />
        <label for="weekday-mon">M</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekDays2" id="weekday-tue2" value="TUE"class="weekday" />
        <label for="weekday-tue">T</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekDays2" id="weekday-wed2" value="WED"class="weekday" />
        <label for="weekday-wed">W</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekDays2" id="weekday-thu2" value="THU" class="weekday" />
        <label for="weekday-thu">T</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekDays2" id="weekday-fri2" value="FRI" class="weekday" />
        <label for="weekday-fri">F</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekDays2" id="weekday-sat2" value="SAT" class="weekday" />
        <label for="weekday-sat">S</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="weekDays2" id="weekday-sun2" value="SUN" class="weekday" />
        <label for="weekday-sun">S</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

For all these rows there is only single submit button.
Likewise for other rows. So there can be many rows with different checkbox ids and names. I don't know how to validate the at least one checkbox selected with the additional condition of schedule type which I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select the group of checkboxes by name and loop the set to test for at least one checked element.

```
function testForCheckedElement(checkboxGroupName){
    let oneChecked = false;
    $( "input[name="+checkboxGroupName+"]" ).each(function( index ) {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            oneChecked = true;
        }
    });
    return oneChecked;
}
```

So you can send the name attribute to the function and test the group:

```
if(tesetForCheckedElement('weekDays1'){
    console.log('at least one element is checked');
}
else{
    console.log('no elements checked in group');
}
```